Checkboxes are blurred and not same size (next + tailwind)
Can someone explain me why are my checkboxes blurred and not same size ?
Here is code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-bhmkek?file=app%2Fpage.jsx

Here image where you can see blurred border on 11 and 1-11 are weird seizes of checkboxes. After 11+ it looks better

Looks to me like the problem starts occurring in the columns, where the number in the header cell gets to two digits ...? If I use dev tools and change that 10 into a 9, then the effect moves one column to the right, and so on. So you probably need to specify the width for those header cells, instead of letting them size according to their text content.

Changed max-w-[1100px] to 1200 and works properly
